# QScrollArea и Layout

Tags: c++, qt, прокрутка

Есть `QScrollArea`. В нее нужно засунуть n-ое количество виджетов так, чтобы все скролилось при нужде. Попробовал туда засунуть `layout` средствами `setLayout()`. Виджеты засовываются в него, но не скролится. На сколько я понял, туда должен быть помещен виджет, внутрь которого уже засовывать тот самый `layout`. Это так или можно сделать это как-то изящнее?

Мое предположение:

```
QScrollArea scroll = new QScrollArea;  
QWidget* widget = new QWidget;
QVBoxLayout* inside = new QVBoxLayout;  
widget->setLayout(inside);  
scroll->setWidget(widget);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должно быть что-то вроде этого:

```
    QScrollArea* scroll = new QScrollArea;
    QWidget* ScrollAreaWidgetContents = new QWidget(scroll);
    QGridLayout* ScrollLayout = new QGridLayout(ScrollAreaWidgetContents);
    QWidget* widget = new QWidget;
    ScrollLayout ->addWidget(widget);
```

И первую строчку желательно заменить на

```
 QScrollArea* scroll = new QScrollArea(this);
```

если, конечно, this указывает на виджет. Предполагаю, что в данном случае у вас this будет QMainWindow. Просто суть в том, что Qt следит за освобождением памяти, но только если у элемента задан родитель

Comment: А если виждет добавлен методом `addWidget()`, то по идее будет Qt так же присвоит виджету данного родителя?

Comment: Согласно QtAssistant, addWidget() использует функцию addItem(), а в описании addItem() указано: The ownership of item is transferred to the layout, and it's the layout's responsibility to delete it. То есть, виджет переходит под контроль лэйаута, и теперь удаление виджета - ответственность этого лэйаута

Comment: Странно, но он все равно не скролит http://imgur.com/cwYBvqN. Вот код http://pastebin.com/G3GMTAG6

Comment: А что именно он должен скроллить? надпись занимает одну строчку. Попробуйте вставить длинный текст, например. Чтобы текст внутри лейбла не уезжал бесконечно вбок, а переносился, нужно ему поставить setWordWrap(true). И еще наверно нужно задать максимальные размеры главного виджета, если не заданы. И если что widget был примером. Если он вам не нужен, то в нем нет смысла)